# Get type of List<T> from object

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a List of Lists, with each list holding a different class of object. To add elements to the correct list, I need to be able to find the type of the list. I am currently trying to accomplish it in this way:

```
        foreach(object o in DataBase)
        {
            Type t = o.GetType();
            if (t != typeof(T))
                continue;
            else
            {
                List<T> L = (List<T>)o;
                L.Add(element);
                break;
            }
         }
```

However, this returns a List Type, of System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[myType,etc,etc]].
Is there a way to extract 'myType' from the type of List, for a proper comparison?

Comment: That looks like a truly horrible solution to a problem.

Comment: It may be - I have only really just started learning reflection. I am open to suggestions though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method:

```
Type listTypeParam = myListType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Since `myListType` is an instance of a generic type with exactly one type parameter, the type `T` will be returned in the 0-th position of the returned array.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. What other sort of information could be contained in the GetGenericArguments()?

Comment: `GetGenericArguments` returns an array of parameters passed to a generic type. The number of elements in the array equals the number of type parameters: for `List<T>` it is always 1; for `Dictionary<K,T>` it is always 2, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Without explicitly checking the generic argument type, you may be able to refactor the above code as:

```
foreach(object o in DataBase)
    if (o is List<T>)
    {
        (o as List<T>).Add(element)
        break;
    }
```